# How to get CDK deployment to fail when it cannot assume role?

Tags: aws-cdk

When running a `cdk deploy` for my application using IAM user credentials that cannot assume the bootstrapped CDK roles I get the following in output:

```
webhooks-comdev-base
current credentials could not be used to assume 'arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/cdk-Wdev-lookup-role-977054617079-us-east-1', but are for the right account. Proceeding anyway.
(To get rid of this warning, please upgrade to bootstrap version >= 8)
```

I am already at bootstrap version 13. I am using CDK version 2.32.1.

I would prefer to fail earlier on the assuming role part. Is there a way I can have the deployment fail when it cannot assume the role instead of trying to proceed with a user that doesn't have correct permissions?

Comment: Hm, any reason you're using such an old version? Have you checked this behavior with a more recent one?

Comment: Just that it may introduce other potential unwanted changes. We could probably upgrade to see if they go away and it behaves differently. Though, even if the warnings went away I would still prefer that it fails rather than trying an account that doesn't have permissions.

Comment: Yeah, I suggest to check with the latest version, it might have the behavior you want.